# cronjob wait understanding

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

bellow is my cronjob script what i want to only

wait for **3rd_job** completion for starting **4th,5th**

& wait for **2nd_job** completion for starting **6,7,8th** job.

how can i achieve this thanks in advance

currently for starting **4,5th** job it is waiting for the completion of **1,2,3th** job but i just want to wait for **3rd** for starting **4,5th** and wait for only **2nd** completion for stating **6,7,8th**

```
    #!/bin/bash
    cd /home/ubuntu/
    PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
    export PATH
    nohup scrapy crawl 1st_job &
    nohup scrapy crawl 2nd_job &
    nohup scrapy crawl 3rd_job &
    wait $(pgrep 3rd_job)
    nohup scrapy crawl 4th_job &
    nohup scrapy crawl 5th_job &
    wait $(pgrep 2nd_job)
    nohup scrapy crawl 6th_job &
    nohup scrapy crawl 7th_job &
    nohup scrapy crawl 8th_job &
```

Comment: .... and then what is your question?

Comment: how can i achieve "what i want"

Comment: You would have to tell us more.  So far, I don't see the cron tab you're trying to use...  Or is this question not really about cron, and more about using job control correctly in shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$!` variable that contains the PID of the last spawned asynchronous task:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ubuntu/
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export PATH
nohup scrapy crawl 1st_job &
nohup scrapy crawl 2nd_job &
pid_2nd="$!"
nohup scrapy crawl 3rd_job &
wait $!
nohup scrapy crawl 4th_job &
nohup scrapy crawl 5th_job &
wait $pid_2nd
nohup scrapy crawl 6th_job &
nohup scrapy crawl 7th_job &
nohup scrapy crawl 8th_job &
```

If you want something a little more complex, for instance execute in a directed acyclic graph fashion (for example as soon as 3rd finishes start 4-5 and as soon 2nd finishes start 6-8) I suggest you reorganize the calls into functions, so that they can be called asynchronously:

```
#!/bin/bash
second () {
    nohup scrapy crawl 2nd_job
    nohup scrapy crawl 6th_job &
    nohup scrapy crawl 7th_job &
    nohup scrapy crawl 8th_job &
}

third () {
    nohup scrapy crawl 3rd_job
    nohup scrapy crawl 4th_job &
    nohup scrapy crawl 5th_job &
}

cd /home/ubuntu/
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export PATH
nohup scrapy crawl 1st_job &
third &
second &
```

Hope this helps =)

Comment: appreciate your answer hopefully it will helps allot , thank you

Comment: can you please expalin 

after3rd &
after2nd & ? are these are some linux commands ?

Comment: Sorry, I changed the function names but forgot to change where they're called. They are simply meant to execute the functions asynchronously.

Comment: do you mean by just not adding "&" at the end it will block next commands till its own execution , soory for a noob question but i am not familiar with linux and commands

Comment: Exactly. Therefore, when the `second` function is executed asynchronously, it will only spawn the 6th, 7th and 8th job (asynchronously) after the 2nd job has finished.